# How to write an SQL query to select recently edited features with Editor Tracking enabled?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2

Conditions: ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 and ArcSDE 10.1

Is there a way to select recently edited features using the automatically populated fields that [Editor Tracking](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000068000000) uses?

The new Editor Tracking feature allows geodatabase managers to track changes to features. There are four new fields that track the creation user/date and the last edit user/date. I'd like to use SQL to identify recently edited ones for other tasks.

The psuedocode would be something like:

```
SELECT FROM [feature] WHERE [editor tracking field] LIKE [2013-11-04]
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? The examples below are for Oracle.

Comment: @blah238 Correct, Oracle. Should that be added in the tags?

Answer (score 2):

Relational operators like `>`, `>=`, and `LIKE` can definitely be used to select from Editor Tracking fields. Here is an example with my data structure

```
SELECT * FROM LANDUSE.TaxParcel WHERE LAST_EDITED_DATE
    > TO_DATE('2013-11-01 19:15:33','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

One interesting note is that the full date/time is not required, so long as the condition has a matching definition in the query. Using the example above, the following are all valid queries:

```
> TO_DATE('2013-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD') -- selects features edited after 01 November 2013
>= TO_DATE('2013-11','YYYY-MM') -- selects features edited in November 2013
LIKE TO_DATE('2013-11-04','YYYY-MM-DD') -- selects dates like 04 November 2013
```

**Procedure in ArcMap 10.2**

1. Using the *Select By Attributes* dialog, set the appropriate layer and select the field in your data that represents the last edit date.
2. Click *Get Unique Values* to see how the query after the operator should be formatted.
3. Build a query with the operator that best fits your algorithm. For example:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM LANDUSE.TaxParcel WHERE LAST_EDITED_DATE
        > TO_DATE('2013-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
   ```
4. Edit the date and time fields as required.